# Unable to process binding afterRender error return on Checkout Page in Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.4

In Magento 2.4, Checkout page I faced error.

```
TypeError : Unable to process binding "afterRender: function () {return renderReCaptcha() }"
```

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create **requiejs-config.js** file and add this mixin :

> **app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_ReCaptchaFrontendUi/js/reCaptcha' : {
                'Vendor_Module/js/reCaptcha-mixin' : true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Create **reCaptcha-mixin.js** file and add below code :

> **app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/reCaptcha-mixin.js**

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'underscore',
    'Magento_ReCaptchaFrontendUi/js/registry',
    'Magento_ReCaptchaFrontendUi/js/reCaptchaScriptLoader',
    'Magento_ReCaptchaFrontendUi/js/nonInlineReCaptchaRenderer'
], function (Component, $, ko, _, registry, reCaptchaLoader, nonInlineReCaptchaRenderer) {
    'use strict';

    return function(Component) {
        return Component.extend({
            initCaptcha: function () {
                if (typeof this.settings === 'undefined') { 
                    return; 
                }
                this._super();
            },
            
            getIsInvisibleRecaptcha: function () {
                if (typeof this.settings === 'undefined') { 
                    return; 
                }
                return this.settings.invisible;
            }
        });   
    }
});
```

Now, Just need to deploy and clean cache.